# Rails query parameter constraints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is there any way I can apply constraints to the query string in Rails routes?

Valid routes: `/path/?type=A` and `/path/?type=B`

Any other type should be invalid route. For eg. `/path/?type=C` should be invalid(400 Bad request)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your action...

```
def my_action
  raise ActionController::BadRequest unless %w(A B).include?(params[:type])
  ... # normal actions here
end
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way to add constraints in routes.rb?

Comment: To routes, yes, to route arguments/parameters no.  That logic belongs in the controller. If you made the arguments hard-coded in the route path, then you could (`path/a` or `path/b`) but you'd probably need to forward to different actions or you'd have to examine the `current_page?` method but I'm not sure it would actually work. 
 https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F Someone smarter than me may have a better answer.

Comment: You could forward to different actions that execute the same code... `def method_a; method('a');end` and `def method_b;method('b');end` and the common logic is in `def method(option)`